# Verify jacoco covarage tests using power mockito without mvn command

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

Is there a way to verify the coverage of jacoco in eclipse without run mvn test command? I'm using power mock, so Eclemma does not work in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EclEmma, powermock and Java 7 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571657/eclemma-powermock-and-java-7-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try a plugin e.g. EclEmma

https://www.eclemma.org/

> Fast develop/test cycle: Launches from within the workbench like JUnit test runs can directly be analyzed for code coverage.
>   Rich coverage analysis: Coverage results are immediately summarized and highlighted in the Java source code editors.
>   Non-invasive: EclEmma does not require modifying your projects or performing any other setup.

Comment: I'm using powermockito.. eclemma don't recognize it